# How to recover a deleted pipeline on AzureDevops SAAS

Tags: azure-devops

We have deleted a pipeline accidentally, we need to recover it but how?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8):

Azure DevOps services gives an out of the box solution for this now.
Simply go to the pipelines overview and click on the 3 dots, click on the view deleted pipelines and recover the pipeline.
[image]

Comment: Is there a specific permission you need to see "View deleted pipelines"?  Does this feature still exist?

Comment: It is available and there is no specific permission mentioned in the release notes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/pipelines/sprint-147-update#restore-deleted-release-pipelines

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is achievable.  But you need to use Rest API to restore the deleted build pipeline.

Here is the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/restore%20definition?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?deleted=false&api-version=5.1
```

It could restore the deleted build definition and  build history.

Here is my restored pipeline:

[image]

Comment: Great that this API exists; however, how would we be able to get the DefinitionId if we don't know it anymore? We just know the name of the deleted deinition.

Comment: Old post but, for anyone else that lands here, the *list* Rest API takes a parameter to include deleted pipelines, you can get the IP from there.

Answer (score 2):

Per the very explicit warning message, this is not something that can be recovered.  At best if you were using the YAML, then you probably will still have your pipeline configuration in the repo.  But you have probably lost the build history and associated artifacts.

[image]